# Ubuntu 13.04 Installation problem: no full installation button in "try Ubuntu"

Tags: installation, 13.04, startup

I already clicked "Try Ubuntu" on Ubuntu 13.04 because there's no full installation button. I dont know why ?

But after restart , It's just skipped to windows boot .

What should I do ?

Comment: from where you have downloaded Ubuntu ?

Comment: from the official site (ubuntu.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, "Try Ubuntu" does what it suggest, you can *try* Ubuntu with it, without installing, of course after restart you will get to your old system.

You can install it by clicking the *Install* icon on the desktop of the Live system.

Comment: I mean , After I clicked "Try Ubuntu" , after restart it should boot an Ubuntu desktop . But after restart my laptop , it's still on windows boot :)

Comment: No it should not, that why it is called *Try*. Ubuntu in this mode runs entirely in RAM. And we know what happens to RAM after restart :)

Comment: I don't know why I don't get the Ubuntu boot after Restart ... .-.
Here's The Thing I Do :
1. I CLicked wubi.exe
2. Clicked Try Ubuntu
3. Ubuntu asks for reboot , then I select reboot now .
*rebooting
and nothing happens ...

Comment: Ah you should have mentioned Wubi, its really a different matter. I didn't used it myself, so hopefully someone else can help.

Comment: If you have UEFI, it is a bit trickier, but yes.

Comment: Are you sure that it was 13.04? There is no support for Wubi in 13.04 onwards...

Comment: yes , the title of the file says "ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64" and there's a wubi.exe inside of the .iso